# Getting self signed error in node js client while making tls connection to the https server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, tls1.2

I am aware this question has been asked in other threads but I am not sure if my problem is discussed.

Doesn't matter which https server I am trying, I keep getting self signed certificate error.

Below is my code snippet:

```
const options = {
            host: `https://google.com`,
            port: 443
        };

   const client = tls.connect(options, () => {
       winston.verbose('Connected to the server via SSL');
       const tokenRequest = {
           hostname: `google.com`,
           port: 443,
           path: '/',
           method: 'GET',
           body: null
           headers: {
               'content-type': 'application/json',
               Accept: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
           },
       };
       const response = https.request(tokenRequest);
       const httpsRequest = https.request(tokenRequest, (httpsResponse) => {
           console.log('HTTP response status code:', httpsResponse.statusCode);

           httpsResponse.on('data', (data) => {
               console.log(data.toString());
           });

           httpsResponse.on('end', () => {
               // Close the TLS socket when the HTTP response is finished.
               client.end();
           });
       });

       httpsRequest.end();
       winston.verbose('requestHokSamlToken response');
   });

   client.on('error', (error) => {
       winston.verbose(`Received: ${error.toString()}`);
   });

   client.on('end', () => {
       winston.verbose('Disconnected from the server');
   });
```

My understanding is I don't need to pass any certs or the key for the ssl handshake from the client as that happens internally during the handshake between client and server.

I also tried changing to other generic servers but getting same error.